# how to create jTextField.checkEmpty()

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, swingx

I have a `jTextField` and I want to check whether or not its values are empty.

So far, I can do it this way:

```
public static JTextField checkEmpty(JTextField jTextField) {
    if (jTextField.getText().equals(" ") || jTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return jTextField;
    }
}
```

However, I want to do it in the manner seen below:

```
JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

jTextField.checkEmpty();
```

This would work by returning a `jTextField` if it is not empty, and throw an exception or show `showMessageDialog` otherwise.

I'm not sure if this is possible, so any help would be appreciated.

With all that said, the actual idea is I want to create a validation class for a swing component in my project. If I can make this work then I can put it in my validation class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own class that extend the JTextField class and add method you want.

- First: you should extend JTextField like:

  ```
  class MyJTextField extends JTextField
  {
    public MyJTextField( String defVal, int size )
     {
       super( defVal, size );
     }
    public MyJTextField()
     {
       super( "", size );
     }

  }
  ```
- Second: you should add your checkEmpty() method, and you don't need the JTextField argument:

  ```
  public MyJTextField checkEmpty() {
  if (this.getText().equals("") || 
      this.getText().isEmpty()) 
    {
      // throw your exception.
      // print message or whatever you need
      return null;
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  }
  ```
- Then: you can use it like this:

  ```
  MyJTextField jTextField = new MyJTextField();

  jTextField.checkEmpty();
  ```

Comment: Think we have 10 JTextField. Do i want to create this one for each and every JTextField.

Comment: No, just one and your 10 JTextField will be instances of this class.